# parsing tweets text from json file in python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am using Python 2.7 and Streaming API from Twitter to get  the tweets related to a particular topic, in a json file. I want to parse the text attribute of each tweet in the json file. My code is as follows:

```
import json

tweets = []
for line in open('science.json'):
    try:
        tweets.append(json.loads(line))
    except:
        continue

print len(tweets)

for tweet in tweets:
    try:
        print tweet['text']
    except:
        pass
```

A sample of my json file is as follows, including two tweets:

```
{"created_at":"Wed Sep 02 11:20:18 +0000 2015","id":639035115457388544,"id_str":"639035115457388544","text":"Police investigate suspected hit-and-run on Oak Street http:\/\/t.co\/B9NnybzIB1 via @lvshepard","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":628694263,"id_str":"628694263","name":"Beth LeBlanc","screen_name":"THBethLeBlanc","location":"","url":null,"description":"Lead investigative reporter for the Times Herald, covering St. Clair and Sanilac County. Retweets, follows, or friends don't equal endorsements.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":654,"friends_count":235,"listed_count":16,"favourites_count":255,"statuses_count":3966,"created_at":"Fri Jul 06 20:18:26 +0000 2012","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C6E2EE","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme2\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme2\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1F98C7","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C6E2EE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DAECF4","profile_text_color":"663B12","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2581088079\/s8mdnulnej4xi3prumpm_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2581088079\/s8mdnulnej4xi3prumpm_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/628694263\/1401363471","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"trends":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/B9NnybzIB1","expanded_url":"http:\/\/bwne.ws\/1EydNoJ","display_url":"bwne.ws\/1EydNoJ","indices":[55,77]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"LVShepard","name":"Liz Shepard","id":85887731,"id_str":"85887731","indices":[82,92]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1441192818880"}

{"created_at":"Wed Sep 02 11:20:21 +0000 2015","id":639035127427923968,"id_str":"639035127427923968","text":"RT @LindaSuhler: Still waiting for Obama to comment on #BlackLivesMatter\u2019s involvement in the deaths of police officers\n***crickets*** http\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":3025146671,"id_str":"3025146671","name":"Douglas MacCrae","screen_name":"DougMac156","location":"Socialist Republic of New York","url":null,"description":"Retired, working toward a right to work nation.  Conservative, Christian, NRA member and veteran, US Army.","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":245,"friends_count":305,"listed_count":4,"favourites_count":315,"statuses_count":1350,"created_at":"Sun Feb 08 16:12:22 +0000 2015","utc_offset":-14400,"time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"89C9FA","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/569517416997068801\/Xb0McW3C_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/569517416997068801\/Xb0McW3C_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/3025146671\/1426075331","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Wed Sep 02 11:03:50 +0000 2015","id":639030968423215104,"id_str":"639030968423215104","text":"Still waiting for Obama to comment on #BlackLivesMatter\u2019s involvement in the deaths of police officers\n***crickets*** http:\/\/t.co\/6cZ82w2Yz3","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eHootsuite\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":347627434,"id_str":"347627434","name":"Linda Suhler, Ph.D.","screen_name":"LindaSuhler","location":"Scottsdale, Arizona","url":null,"description":"Unapologetic Constitutional Conservative #1A #2A #NRA #StandWithIsrael #TCOT #CCOT #LNYHBT #ProLife #SupportMilitary #BlueLivesMatter #GodBlessAmerica","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":146662,"friends_count":111351,"listed_count":1345,"favourites_count":12296,"statuses_count":111887,"created_at":"Wed Aug 03 03:00:30 +0000 2011","utc_offset":-25200,"time_zone":"Arizona","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"0040FF","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/435620049223573504\/FnzC5S_5.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/435620049223573504\/FnzC5S_5.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"FF0F0F","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"A0C5C7","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/460575901046943744\/8mLlMfiL_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/460575901046943744\/8mLlMfiL_normal.jpeg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/347627434\/1420230815","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":34,"favorite_count":25,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"BlackLivesMatter","indices":[38,55]}],"trends":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":638810803416625152,"id_str":"638810803416625152","indices":[118,140],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/6cZ82w2Yz3","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/6cZ82w2Yz3","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/LindaSuhler\/status\/638810803823472640\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":340,"h":267,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"}},"source_status_id":638810803823472640,"source_status_id_str":"638810803823472640"}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":638810803416625152,"id_str":"638810803416625152","indices":[118,140],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/6cZ82w2Yz3","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/6cZ82w2Yz3","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/LindaSuhler\/status\/638810803823472640\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":340,"h":267,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"}},"source_status_id":638810803823472640,"source_status_id_str":"638810803823472640"}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"BlackLivesMatter","indices":[55,72]}],"trends":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"LindaSuhler","name":"Linda Suhler, Ph.D.","id":347627434,"id_str":"347627434","indices":[3,15]}],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":638810803416625152,"id_str":"638810803416625152","indices":[139,140],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/6cZ82w2Yz3","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/6cZ82w2Yz3","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/LindaSuhler\/status\/638810803823472640\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":340,"h":267,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"}},"source_status_id":638810803823472640,"source_status_id_str":"638810803823472640"}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":638810803416625152,"id_str":"638810803416625152","indices":[139,140],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/CN2DCohUcAA4Yf1.jpg","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/6cZ82w2Yz3","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/6cZ82w2Yz3","expanded_url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/LindaSuhler\/status\/638810803823472640\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"small":{"w":340,"h":267,"resize":"fit"},"medium":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":500,"h":394,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"}},"source_status_id":638810803823472640,"source_status_id_str":"638810803823472640"}]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1441192821734"}
```

After I run this script, I get the number of tweets as 895 but it prints only around 30 tweets and stops. Any reason friends?

Comment: Any particular reason you're parsing each individual line of the json file as a separate block of json text? Isn't the whole file the json you want to parse?

Comment: I wonder how the file is being read in. Are there newlines and other formatting that could screw up the read? Sounds like you would have seen that by now...but i don't have other ideas yet.

Comment: You should include an example of the input file for which you are getting issue.

Comment: Anand S Kumar, I have mentioned the name of the file . It is 'science.json'

Comment: You need to provide more than the name of the file for help. Give us a sample of the json file that you are trying to read from.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are reading line-by-line from a json file which has its own formatting.

Instead of reading line-by-line, try:

```
with open('science.json') as tweet_data:
    json_data = json.load(tweet_data)
```

That way, you read all the data at once and can load it as a file-like object with the json module.

If that doesn't work, you may have an issue with how your json is formatted in that file.

Also, you don't need the `try` and `except` statements within a `with` statement. The `with` statement already uses it for you! :)

Comment: i tried above but it doesn't work. Again, the same problem. So, I have put a sample of my json file.

Answer (score 0):

First load the data

```
all_data = json.loads(data)
```

Then get the tweets

```
tweet = all_data["text"]
```